# What is the proper way to get a string and int value of it when using itext for reading a PDF?

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, itext, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a PDF file in Java by using Itext. In my PDF file I have some calculation results. In a line there is an element and its two calculation results and they are not in a table. My PDF file looks like this :

```
  I. Result X                          12.551.734,75       9.284.925,26
    . A. Result Y                      8.583.482,18        416.187,03
       . 1. result z                   83.708,72           91.220,23
       . 3. result a                   8.499.773,46        324.966,80
     . B. Result B                     0,00                199.942,00
        . 4. result c                  0,00                199.942,00
      . C. Result D                    780.316,81          5.376.366,65
        . 1. result e                  66.041,73           3.962.399,52
        . 2. result f                  685.579,00          1.367.086,66
```

What I am trying to do is parse the string and its values. I couldn't find a proper way and I tried the code below. But the problem with this logic for the line :

> `. 1. result z    8.583.482,18        416.187,03`

it prints just **"."** for the string then **1** and **the first number**. I couldn't get the whole **". 1. result z"** part as string and then its values because it prints directly after seeing an int value and skips rest.

```
int page = 1;
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
strategy = parser.processContent(page, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(strategy.getResultantText());

...

for (int j = page; j <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); j++) {

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String nextToken = scanner.nextLine();

                String rName = "";
                StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(nextToken);
                while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String nToken = tok.nextToken();
                    try {
                        number = fmt.parse(nToken);
                        System.out.println(rName);
                        System.out.println(number);
                        while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                            try {
                                nToken = tok.nextToken();
                                number = fmt.parse(nToken);
                                System.out.println(number);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                if(rName.isEmpty()){
                                    rName = nToken;
                                }else{
                                    rName = rName + " " + nToken;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        if(rName.isEmpty()){
                            rName = nToken;
                        }else{
                            rName = rName + " " + nToken;
                        }
                    }                   
                }       
            }
            strategy = parser.processContent(++page, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
            scanner = new Scanner(strategy.getResultantText());
        }
```

How can I get these strings and their values correctly, could you help me please? Is there any other useful way to do it as I think this solution is not good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the detail you provided. Typically you'd use a regular expression to parse complicated lines. Though sometimes programmatic parsing is a bit easier to follow. Rather than using the StringTokenizer to split the line, perhaps try:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();

String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
String value1 = tokens[tokens.length-2];
String value2 = tokens[tokens.length-1];

String rowTitle = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(value1)).trim();

System.out.print(rowTitle + "\t");
System.out.print(value1 + "\t");
System.out.println(value2);
```

Comment: thank you, it's a very easy solution and it solved my problem for now.